# Using jQuery end() function with Destructive methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I'm having some problems grokking the .end() function in jQuery. The docs I've read advertise it as "rolling back" changes from a filter or additional selection. For example,

```
var someDivs = $('div');
someDivs
  .filter('li')
  .css('color', 'green')
.end(); // ok, reverted back to original wrapper
```

On the other hand, this doesn't work.

```
someDivs
  .get(0) // get DOM element at index 0
.end(); // error, executing a jQuery method on a plain javascript object.
```

I'm just trying to verify that I'm correct that after certain chain-destructive methods like html(), text(), and get() are called, it's impossible to revert back to the original wrapper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not impossible. `$(someDivs.get(0)).end();`. Gonna update my answer and add this in.

Comment: @Khez, that won't work sadly. It is equivalent to selecting elements from scratch again, in which case... where does `end()` go to?

Comment: @Box9 ... uhh you're wrong. [A DOM element to wrap in a jQuery object.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: @Khez I'm not sure you understood me as I don't see how the link is relevant. My question is, what will `end()` return if the only information passed into `$()` is a single DOM element?

Comment: @Box9 ohh, that's what you meant, thought you meant I can't pass a DOM element to $(). I was proving that the function call doesn't fail, not that it leads anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `end()` will only work on methods that return a jQuery object.  Methods that return strings (`.html()`, `.text()`) or DOM elements (`.get()`) won't allow you to chain any jQuery methods at all subsequently.

Answer (score 3):

[get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Get#.get.28.29_-_DOM_manipulation) returns an actual HTML DOM Element not a jQuery element. You need to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
someDivs.eq(0).end();
```

If you ever need to return to a jQuery object context from a dom element. You can always throw the element into $(). For example the above statement can be rewritten:

```
$(someDivs.get(0)).end();
```

^ This is exactly why you do `$(this)` in most event handlers. You're getting passed the DOM element not a jQuery object.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of that, since he mentioned `.html()` and `.text()` as well.

Comment: no, the .end() will not get you back someDivs.

doing the .get(0) returns a DOM element, and as such loses the original list history.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct, as those "destructive" functions return values that are *not* jQuery objects.

However, you don't even need to use `.end()` when you store your selection in a variable (e.g. `someDivs`). None of jQuery's traversal functions (`children()`, `filter()`, etc...) actually modify the jQuery object they are applied on, but return a new one instead. This section of the jQuery docs is very helpful in understanding what occurs during chaining:

> Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods
>   operate on a jQuery object instance
>   and produce a new one, matching a
>   different set of DOM elements. When
>   this happens, it is as if the new set
>   of elements is pushed onto a stack
>   that is maintained inside the object.
>   Each successive filtering method
>   pushes a new element set onto the
>   stack. If we need an older element
>   set, we can use `end()` to pop the sets
>   back off of the stack.

Since the original jQuery object is not modified, instead of using `.end()`, you can simply reference the original:

```
var html = someDivs.filter('li').html();
var text = someDivs.filter('p').text();
```